# Remote connect OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I've got an Ubuntu server running at home, and it's connected to a OpenVPN server. The OpenVPN remote address is `176.126.237.214`, with port `25000`. This tunnel connection changes my public IP to a IP given out by my OpenVPN server. At the moment I can't connect to my personal Ubuntu server remotely. I've already tried opening the port used by my server, `192.168.1.11`, with port `8882`. How can I remote SSH connect to my personal server?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to connect using your server's original (non-VPN) IP address?

The problem is that the default gateway gets changed by OpenVPN, and that breaks any connection coming in on the non-VPN interface. Linux will send responses to packets that came in on the real interface out the VPN interface! You need to set up appropriate routes before you start OpenVPN.

What follows works for me. It uses iptables and ip (iproute2). Below, it is assumed that the default gateway interface before OpenVPN is started is "eth0". The idea is to ensure that when a connection to eth0 is made, even if eth0 is not the default gateway interface anymore, response packets for the connection go back on eth0 again.

You could use the same number for the connection mark, firewall mark and routing table. I used distinct numbers to make the diffences between them more apparent.

```
# set "connection" mark of connection from eth0 when first packet of connection arrives
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234

# set "firewall" mark for response packets in connection with our connection mark
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321

# our routing table with eth0 as gateway interface
sudo ip route add default dev eth0 table 3412

# route packets with our firewall mark using our routing table
sudo ip rule add fwmark 4321 table 3412
```

===

UPDATE:

The above works fine for me on Debian Jessie. But on an older Wheezy system I have just found that I need to add "via" to the routing table entry:

```
# our routing table with eth0 as gateway interface
sudo ip route add default dev eth0 via 12.345.67.89 table 3412
```

There "12.345.67.89" must be the original non-VPN gateway.